# When to return vector iterator instead of vector?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

Let's say we have a function 1 :

```
vector<T>::iterator GetSomething()
{
 vector<T> vec;

 // Update vec with something...

 return vec.begin();
}
```

And another function 2:

```
vector<T> GetSomething()
{
 vector<T> vec;

 // Update vec with something...

 return vec;
}
```

In what situations would we prefer function 1 ? 
Also, what would be the lifetime of that vector object ? 
How would we know if the iterator is pointing to empty vector ? Probably need to pass pair of iterators to determine begin / end.

Comment: We never prefer option 1 that is in this post, because the iterator is invalid. The associated vector has gone out of scope.

Comment: Function 1 returns an iterator into something that does not exist, and can therefore never be used correctly. This makes function 2 look almost good by comparison.

Comment: @KerrekSB - Why almost? NRVO and move semantics make it good on its own.

Comment: Have you over-simplified, and these are actually members of a class, and the vector is also a class member?  In that case, the question becomes much more interesting.

Comment: @cruskal Sometimes it is better to post a new question, because your update invalidates some of the answers.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Will take of that in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't return iterator to locally allocated vector. It is an undefined behavior.

The explanation is pretty simple: `vector<T> vec;` is destroyed once you leave the function.

The second option is better and most probably will have *Return Value Optimization* that will construct vector exactly where it should be returned.

Answer (score 2):

A vector iterator is only valid for the vector it comes from so returning an iterator to a local vector is no use.

Only return a vector iterator when you passed the vector it belongs to in as a parameter reference:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator find(std::vector<int>& v, int i)
{
    // do findie stuff
    return std::find(std::begin(v), std::end(v), i);
}
```

You would *never* want to do this:

```
vector<T>::iterator GetSomething()
{
    vector<T> vec;

    // Update vec with something...

    return vec.begin(); // this iterator will be bad when it arrives
}
```

Once the vector is destroyed at the end of the function its iterators are invalidated.

Comment: Good answer, but maybe template the first/correct example, just so it matched the question.

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius My preference is to keep the example simple as some readers may not be using templates in their own code. Although the original question uses `T` its not actually presented as a template function.

Answer (score 0):

The lifetime of vector, just like all other automatic variables ends with the scope of the block it was declared in.

As such, if you return the iterator, it will point to freed memory and do all kinds of funny things like crash your program.

If you return the vector itself, it is copied with all of its content, but the original vector still 'dies' at the end of the block.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the general remark about returning a pointer-like to something disapparead on the stack, option 1 asks for a pair of *methods* (functions disqualify option 1) : begin & end. Iterators in C++ do not work as in java, python and many others.

Answer (score 0):

There is no circumstance in which your first function would be preferred.  The vector `vec` ceases to exist when the function returns.  Any iterators supplied by that vector will be invalid for the caller.   And most usages of those iterators (particularly dereferencing) will cause the caller to exhibit undefined behaviour.

The only time an iterator should be returned by a function will be if the vector which provides those iterators is guaranteed to exist after the function returns.   Practically, there are only three circumstances in which one MIGHT do that.  The first is if the vector is passed as an argument to the function, such as

```
 std::vector<int>::iterator func(std::vector<int> &vec)
 {
     return vec.begin();
 }
```

Since the caller passes the vector, the vector will exist when the function returns.

The second case is if the vector is a static, or otherwise continues to exist when the function returns.

```
 std::vector<int>::iterator func(std::vector<int> &vec)
 {
     static std::vector<int> vec;
     return vec.begin();
 }
```

Of course, using a function like this has all the complications associated with statics (e.g. problems with reentrancy, need to synchronise usage across threads, etc etc).

The third case in which an iterator may be returned is if an iterator is passed to the function.  Such as

```
 std::vector<int>::iterator func(std::vector<int>::iterator it)
 {
     return it + 1;
 }
```

In this case, it is up to the caller to pass a valid iterator (e.g. obtained from a container it controls) that can be incremented (or advanced by 1).

Also, if a function returns an iterator, the caller might need to check if the iterator is valid before using it.   If so, that should be docuumented.  For example, if the function might return an end iterator, the caller should check BEFORE trying to dereference it, not after.

Comment: What if the vector is a member variable ?

Comment: That's another case, but your example was of standalone functions, not member functions.   It's not really a good idea for a class to provide access - directly or indirectly - to private members.  Returning an iterator to a vector that is a member is like returning a reference or pointer to a member, in effect - it allows code outside the class to change private data without any control bu the class.

Comment: I intended to ask that question, somehow posted with a local vector. We could return const iterator